# Angular front-end not showing anything in the web

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm following Thinkster's AnuglarJS on Rails tutorial(https://thinkster.io/angular-rails#jumping-in-with-angular).

Here is what I made so far. https://jsfiddle.net/dcbavw4e/

I do not see anything on the web. I did install node.js and npm. Is there anything I should install to run Angular web or run?

Maybe there's something wrong with my script lines?

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

[updated]
Here is the error I'm getting
[image]

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Did you even start server? Side note...that's an ld version you are using

Comment: Above comment should say *"that's an old version"*

Comment: Changed the version for angular and still not showing anything

Comment: Need more feedback on what is or isn't working. The version was a side note and not related directly to problem. You never mentioned if you started node server and are even able to access it in browser

Comment: my bad. I'm running node server and all I see is just white blank webpage. routes and everything are fine. But I just don't see anything.

Comment: So what about errors in browser dev tools console? Or files not loading in dev tools network?

Comment: Updated with error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed many things in `jsfiddle` example please correct bellow things.

**In `app.js` file:**

1. after `.state('home'` complete use `;` no need to use this use `.` instead of `;`
2. After `.factory('posts'...)` used `;` no need to use this
3. Used `$scope.incrementUpvotes(post)` use just `$scope.incrementUpvotes= function(post)`
4. `.controller('PostsCtrl'` declare inside `controller('MainCtrl'` should be out od `MainCtrl`
5. Should avoid `@` from `@stateParams.id`

**In HTML:**

1. remove last 
           `</form>
       </script>`

then should be work fine.

See [PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EGRfBgGKJsLpIfow3z59?p=preview) removed your error and working. Here I used `script.js` instead of `app.js` in plunker demo

It may will help you

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I was wrong blatantly wrong about script tags as pointed out by the comments, my apologies! and Thanks to the commenters for pointing that out.

*You have a couple of issues going on here:*

1. You have closing script and form tags at the bottom which have no opening tag
2. Per the fiddle, you need to add the external resources in the left side panel not directly in your `HTML`, that said, it is exactly how you should do it in your own files, this is only a JSFiddle thing.
3. Finally, node has nothing to do with the code you have here. Node is just javascript on the backend, should be find with the corrections outlined here and the corrected JSFiddle below. Just open up your `HTML` file in your browser.
4. I didn't fix everything for you, some of the Angular is still broken, but thats why you're taking the tutorial right? Good luck!

*note the 3 external resources in the right hand panel of the page!

[Correct Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/dcbavw4e/1/)

Comment: #1 is completely wrong. Using templates in script tags is well documented

Comment: I'm following Thinkster's tutorial and they use script (ng-template) to show different views depends on URl

Comment: You can put anything you want inside a script tag so long is it is a `type` that browser doesn't recognize as script